# Elasticsearch terms query on 32-bit floats behaving oddly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-6.8

With Elasticsearch v6.8.5 and v7.11.0, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the behavior of floats being cast to doubles and losing precision, thus breaking my `term` queries.

For tech debt reasons, I've got an index mapping of type `float`:

```json
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "cid": {
        "type" : "float",
        "ignore_malformed": false,
        "coerce" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After indexing two documents containing the `cid`s 2219658785 and 2219658651:

```json
POST test/_doc
{
  "cid": 2219658785
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "cid": 2219658651
}
```

and querying for `2219658785`:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cid": {
        "value": 2219658785
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uniqueByCid": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "cid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- **both** documents are returned
- and the **cardinality** of the `cid` **is 1**.

Very odd.

If I retain the mapping and index much smaller `cid`s, e.g. `1` and `2`, the term query does work as expected – only 1 document is returned.

So, I figure that my large `cid`s don't fit into `float` and are cast do `doubles` because

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "Debug.explain(doc['cid']);"
    }
  }
}
```

prints out [`ScriptDocValues.Doubles`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.11.0/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.Doubles.html).

To inspect further, I run a script utilizing `DecimalFormat`:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": """
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
          
          def val = doc['cid'].value;
          
          Debug.explain([val, df.format(val)]);
      """
    }
  }
}
```

and I see:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "runtime error",
        "painless_class" : "java.util.ArrayList",
        "to_string" : "[2.219658752E9, 2219658752]",
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Assuming the document from above contains `cid: 2219658785`, Elasticsearch has cast 2219658785 to 2219658752.
But for `cid: 2219658651`, the script also prints out 2219658752!

Apparently, the "casted" `float`s (or rather `long`s?) seem to be capped at 2219658752.

So my questions are:

1. What's so special about 2219658752? I understood 32-Bit floats to be [capped at (2-2^-23) × 2^127](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use) which is significantly higher than 2219658785. Is it not?
2. Can I target my `cid`s with a `term` query or do I have to reindex with `long`s or `double`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's so special about 2219658752? I understood 32-Bit floats to be capped at (2-2^-23) × 2^127 which is significantly higher than 2219658785. Is it not?

The important part in the table that you linked is not the max value but significant bits/digits. If you take a look at how [float is structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Once your cannot fit into significant bits you start loosing precision. So while it can represent number significantly higher then your number, it starts loosing precision after you reach `16777216`. Anything about 16,777,217 several number will be mapped into a single value.

So, to answer your question there is nothing special about 2,219,658,785. It's just cannot fit into float without losing precision. In this case you are loosing a bit less than 3 last decimal points. So basically all numbers between 2,219,658,624 and 2,219,658,880 are represented as the same value in elasticsearch and elasticsearch will not be able to see the difference between these numbers.

Comment: Thank you Igor! So if the large numbers are "represented as the same value in elasticsearch", reindexing is the only way to go, right? The doc values too are already "malformed" at this point, right?

Comment: The doc values are not malformed. They correspond to the IEEE standard, which specifies how many significant digits have to be stored, and doc value do just that - store values with the standard-specified precision that happened to be less than you need. So, yeah, the only place where the required precision is still kept is _source, so you need to reindex. I am not sure how cids are generated in your case but you probably need `long`, `unsigned_long` or maybe even keyword if they can be longer  than what you can fit into 64 bit.

Comment: Right. OK makes sense. `long` it is. Thanks again!